# android fragment - how to inflate the layout and then make the UI functions

Tags: java, android, fragment

I have a `Fragment` instance, and I would like to be able to implement click listeners and other attributes after the fragment is loaded and shown on screen.  How can I achieve this?  Where should I be doing this implenentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rap_prog_fields, container, false);
    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_view_1);
    Button b = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             //do stuff
         }
     });
    //the rest of your views... in the same manner

    return v;
}
```

You can also find your views after returning from `onCreateView` like such:

```
public void onStart() {
     super.onStart();
     Button b = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.button);
     b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             //do stuff
         }
     });
     //Everything else...
 }
```

TO complete actions once the view is displayed and on the screen you need to implement the following:

```
final ViewTreeObserver observer= button.getViewTreeObserver(); //you need an anchor view here that will be drawn via xml
       observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                //do stuff here.....
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm doing it but all setting of things like onClickListeners must come before returning the view, I'm trying to set stuff after returning and showing the view

Comment: the onStart() is called after the onCreateView but its still before the layout is shown on the screen, what can I do to do stuff only after the inflated layout is on screen?

Comment: where should I put the OnGlobalLayoutListener()?

Comment: Why do you want to do this after it is on the screen anyways? You can do it right from onStart or onResume... You will need to update your question with more details. There is not enough to understand what you want.

Comment: I'm doing it because I have a very heavy function in my fragment, I want to call it after the layout is on the screen to prevent the delay, do you have another solution?

Comment: There are no other solutions as far as I know. You either complete the action in one of the lifecycle events or after the view is displayed with the `onGlobalLayout`.

Comment: I still have a delay when Im using the onGlobalLayout do you have any idea why? thanks for helping anyway.

Comment: There is going to be a delay because the layout has to wait for the function to complete AFTER the view has become visible, instead of doing it while the fragment is in creation.

Comment: I know, I just prefer to have the delay with a visible view rather then having the delay with nothing visible

Comment: so use the `onGlobalLayout` and then use an indeterminate laoding circle to force the user to wait for the function to complete.

Comment: the delay is still before the view i visible